# How to show updating animation during HTTP request

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-phone-7

I've noticed many of the apps do an "Updating..." animation at the top of the screen while they're making HTTP requests. How do I make that happen in my app while I'm waiting for an async request to return?

I suppose the method that initiates the request somehow triggers the animation, and the one that handles the eventual response stops it. Or does it automatically detect when there is network traffic?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a hidden `ProgressBar`, set to **indeterminate** mode to get the dots.

Show it when you start the request and then hide it when the request completes. (or if it errors)

*See comments below for performance considerations & alternatives.*

e.g.

```
webclient.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri("http://example.com"));
progress.IsIndeterminate = true;
progress.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
```

and

```
void dl_DownloadStringCompleted2(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    progress.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
    progress.IsIndeterminate = false;
    ...
}
```

*updated with performance suggestions from comments. thanks*

Comment: Ah. I thought it was something fancier. Thanks.

Comment: By the way, I had to do `Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(HideLoader);` from the response handler because of the way my code's written and a similar call for showing it.

Comment: Please note - if you are using the ProgressBar in indeterminate mode, then please use one of the high performance variations - http://www.jeff.wilcox.name/2010/08/performanceprogressbar/ - now also in the SL WP7 Toolkit.

Comment: To add to what @Stuart said, even with the PerformanceProgressBar, make sure you also set `IsIndeterminate` to false when the progress bar is hidden, and set it true only when you make the progress bar visible.

Answer (score 1):

Using ProgressBar.IsIndeterminate eats more than 60% of CPU resources. It may kill some apps (if they need to do a lot CPU cycles) or just drain the battery.

Alternatives are described [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/showcase/WP7-Animations.aspx?msg=3811440#xx3811440xx)

Answer (score 1):

I would also suggest to use Progressbar from [Silverligt Toolkit](http://silverlight.codeplex.com/), due to performance reasons (it runs on diferent thread than UI, more deatils can be read [here](http://www.windowsphonegeek.com/articles/WP7-PerformanceProgressBar-in-depth))